# Problem in accelerating the list lookup function in python using numba

Tags: python, performance, numba

I need to accelerate the list lookup function using code optimization/vectorization/parallel processing on multiple cores. For that reason, I started with the tool numba to perform parallelization and fast math. At first I used the same function and just used a decorator after downloading numba by enabling the knobs to run the function faster. But it shows that the error is happening at *obsest_t*. The *idexs* is a list with 1024 randomly generated numbers and data is a buffer which is almost greater than 30K elements.

Here's the code:

```
@njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
    def _encode_sample(self, idxes):
        obses_t, actions, rewards, obses_tp1, dones = [], [], [], [], []
        for i in idxes:
            data = self._storage[i]
            obs_t, action, reward, obs_tp1, done = data
            obses_t.append(np.array(obs_t, copy=False))
            actions.append(np.array(action, copy=False))
            rewards.append(reward)
            obses_tp1.append(np.array(obs_tp1, copy=False))
            dones.append(done)
        return np.array(obses_t), np.array(actions), np.array(rewards), np.array(obses_tp1), np.array(dones)
```

Error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at /home/kailash/Desktop/maddpg/maddpg/trainer/replay_buffer.py (41)

File "../maddpg/trainer/replay_buffer.py", line 41:
    def _encode_sample(self, idxes):
        obses_t, actions, rewards, obses_tp1, dones = [], [], [], [], []
        ^ 

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'maddpg.trainer.replay_buffer.ReplayBuffer'>

Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

My python version is 3.7.13 and numba version is 0.56.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot JIT function that are part of a class that way. You need to use a **`jitclass`** or not to use classes (typically if some functions cannot be jitted). This feature is experimental so use it at your own risk. For more information, please read the [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jitclass.html) about it.